# Pass some properties to a directive in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I created a directive (itcValidationMessages) which will let me display a validations messages and I put it on the form element as an attribute like below:

```
<form id="register-form" novalidate ng-submit="register()" itc-validation-messages ...
```

Directive that I mentioned above, iterates through all of input elements within the form and displays the error messages if anyone has an invalid state.

I store a validation messages in the separate file (because there can be a lot of them and I want to be prepare for i8n so I've separated them from directive) like this:

```
angular.module('models.ValidationMessages', []).constant("ValidationMessages", {
validationMessages: {
    required: 'Value is required!',
    email: 'You should enter a valid email address!',
    minlength: 'Enter more characters!',
    maxlength: 'You have entered to many characters!'
}
```

});

Is it a correct way to put those messages in constant?

I have a default message for each validator, but I want to let to add a custom messages for each input e.g.:

```
<input type="password" minlength-message="Your password should has at least 3 characters"
```

What is a the best way to do it?
Because why I use an attribute like above (minlength-message) I cannot get access to it from my directive without using `$observe`.
I don't want to declare one object and put those custom messages in one place, because I should then add to each of message an input name to recognize for which input them belong.
So I try to find some convenient and according to art solution.

I don't need an isolated scope in the itcValidationMessages directive and I don't want a separate directive for each validator like minlengthMessage to pass specific validation message to my directive which should display this message (itcValidationMessages).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example on how to access data from the directive:

```
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', [])
    .directive('myComponent', function () {
        return {
            restrict:'E',
            scope:{
                minlengthMessage:'@'
            }        
        };
    })
```

So now you can get the string from

```
$scope.minlengthMessage
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is not what I meant. I've clarified a bit my description, sorry if I was confusing.

Comment: I don't want have a another directive, since I have one on the form element. I have to connect those validation messages in some way with each input and have a access to them from my directive.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use attrs passed to directive link function.

Here is an example:

```
.directive('minlength', function () {
     return {
          restrict: 'EA',
          link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
              var myDirectiveParam = $attrs.minlengthMessage;
          }
     };
})
```

And in your HTML:

```
<input minlength minlength-message="Your message here.." />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is not what I meant. I've clarified a bit my description, sorry if I was a confusing. The point is that I want to have a one directive on form element and many messages connected to each input.

Comment: Btw. why did you use the dollar sign in the injections of your link function?